# php mysql select not working on field "name"

Tags: php, mysql

I know it's strange but I have a select that returns null if the field named **name** is used. If I remove it then it works, and I already changed the data in the table. If I make a direct query to mysql it works. There might be something in the contents but I can't see anything strange.

Any suggestion that could help me investigate is welcome :(

```
class go { 
   function Query($sql){

       $results = $this->db->query($sql);

       if (mysqli_num_rows($results)<1){    
           throw new Exception('No Results');       
       }    

       $out = array();

       while ($r = $results->fetch_object()){       
           $out[] = $r;  
       } 

       return json_encode($out);    

       $out = null;
    }
}

$client = new go;

//not working
$sql = "select name from books limit 10"; 
$sql = "select name,description from books limit 10";
$sql = "select * from books limit 10";

// works!
$sql = "select description from books limit 10"; 

$data = $client->Query( $sql );
```

**UPDATE**

I found that the problem comes out due to some latin accented characters like ó ñ é

Comment: you must use ``
for exp :
select \`name\`,\`description\` from \`books\` limit 10

Comment: Well, *name* is not a reserved keyword

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

DBMS some reserved keywords. Name is a reserved name in MYsQL. Change the name to another column name, maybe name1. I think that should work.Check list of reserved keywords for mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N.

Comment: Then why `select *` doesn't work ?

Comment: in * is the name inside. Because * select all your columns.

Comment: Well, no. `select *` selects all fields, no matter how they are named. *Name* is not a reserved word, the issue is in fact about character encoding

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try setting the charset when initialising the connection to your mySQL server usg [`set_charset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset) method. I use the following charset:

```
$this->db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

This may resolve your issue.

Comment: @Cid, I have updated my answer to correct the nomenclature.

Comment: I found that the problem comes out due to some latin accented characters like ó ñ é - How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with 
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");